# For loop - Notice a change in directory from a list of files

Tags: batch-file

I have a `mytextfile.txt` file that contains a list of files I want to process.

#### The list looks like this:

```
"Z:\Folder 1\filename 01.doc"
"Z:\Folder 1\filename 02.doc"
"Z:\Folder 2\filename 01.doc"
"Z:\Folder 2\filename 02.doc"
"Z:\Folder 2\filename 03.doc"
"Z:\Folder 3\filename 01.doc"
```

#### My code:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%D in (mytextfile.txt) do (
 :: I only want to echo the directory every time it comes across a different one.
 echo Directory - "%%~dpD"
 :: Here is fine, I want to process the files now in the code below.
 echo Filename  - "%%~nD"
 )
```

#### This outputs to the buffer:

```
Directory - "Z:\Folder 1\"
Filename  - "filename 01"
Directory - "Z:\Folder 1\"
Filename  - "filename 02"
Directory - "Z:\Folder 2\"
Filename  - "filename 01"
Directory - "Z:\Folder 2\"
Filename  - "filename 02"
Directory - "Z:\Folder 2\"
Filename  - "filename 03"
Directory - "Z:\Folder 3\"
Filename  - "filename 01"
```

#### Whereas this is the desired output:

```
Directory - "Z:\Folder 1\"
Filename  - "filename 01"
Filename  - "filename 02"
Directory - "Z:\Folder 2\"
Filename  - "filename 01"
Filename  - "filename 02"
Filename  - "filename 03"
Directory - "Z:\Folder 3\"
Filename  - "filename 01"
```

Notice how the directory is only output once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following technique simply saves the parent directory names as a variable, then checks that against the previous value in order to determine whether to `Echo` it:

```batch-file
@SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
@For %%G In (PDir PPDir)Do @Set "%%G="
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%Sort.exe" "mytextfile.txt" 2>NUL"'
)Do @(Set "PDir=%%~dpG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If /I Not "!PPDir!"=="!PDir!" Echo Directory - "!PDir:~,-1!"
    EndLocal
    Echo Filename  - "%%~nG"
    Set "PPDir=%%~dpG")
@Pause
@EndLocal
```

This is untested but I'd expect its output to look like this:

```batch-file
Directory - "Z:\Folder 1"
Filename  - "filename 01"
Filename  - "filename 02"
Directory - "Z:\Folder 2"
Filename  - "filename 01"
Filename  - "filename 02"
Filename  - "filename 03"
Directory - "Z:\Folder 3"
Filename  - "filename 01"
```

You'll note that I've used `sort` to first ensure that any repetition of paths anywhere within the text file are returned together.

If you don't want to use `sort`, then this should suffice:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Title Outputting directories and their files from a file list
Color 5F
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "ITF=%Temp%\music-checker-list.txt"
For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ('ChCp') Do For %%H In (%%G) Do Set "CCp=%%~nH"
If Not %CCp% Equ 65001 ChCp 65001 >NUL
For %%G In (PDir PPDir)Do @Set "%%G="
For /F "UseBackDelims=" %%G In ("%ITF%")Do (Set "PDir=%%~dpG"
    Set "NFile=%%~G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If /I Not "!PPDir!"=="!PDir!" Echo Directory - "!PDir:~,-1!"
    Call :Process_Files "!NFile!"
    EndLocal
    Set "PPDir=%%~dpG")
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Process_Files
Echo Full file name - %1
Exit /B
```

The answer above has been adjusted in order that the modified name list and its subsequent edit section code in your own provided answer correctly handle the ampersands and percent characters.

Comment: I've amended the examples. Thanks for letting me know. I'll test this out now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I needed to `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` then check the directory then `EndLocal` again. Thanks once again. I'll add what I've settled on as an answer without the sorting bit.

Comment: How can this handle calling a function to run on files with `%` in them? It's failing if I put in `call :PROCESS_FILES "%%~D"` in place of `Echo Filename  - "%%~nG"`. With `PROCESS_FILES` simply having `echo "%~1" && goto :EOF`

Comment: Seeing as some others might come across this issue. I've added the fix to my version of your answer below.

Comment: Well the example in your edited answer is not what you asked above, it shows only directories with ampersands and percent characters, not filenames. I have removed my previous comment, which is therefore no longer relevant. I have also modified the last example code in my answer above to handle the ampersands and percent characters.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @Compo here's what I've settled on:

```batch-file
@echo off & title Example to go through a list of file and echo, Directory then files... & color 5F & chcp 65001 >NUL
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "fileList=%temp%\file-list.txt"

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%D in (!fileList!) do (
  set "dirBase=%%~dpD"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  if /i not "!dirNext!"=="!dirBase!" echo Directory - "!dirBase:~,-1!"
  endlocal
  echo Filename  - "%%~nD"
  set "dirNext=%%~dpD"
  )
```

---

### EDIT

#### In order for a call to be made to another function...

Any `%` symbols need to be doubled up in order for this to happen.

Take this `file-list.txt` file for example:

```batch-file
"Z:\Folder 100%\filename 01.doc"
"Z:\Folder 100%\filename 02.doc"
"Z:\Folder 100%\filename 01.doc"
"Z:\Folder 100%\filename 02.doc"
"Z:\Folder 100%\filename 03.doc"
"Z:\Folder 100%\filename 01.doc"
"Z:\Folder & 100%\filename 01.doc"
"Z:\Folder & 100%\filename 02.doc"
"Z:\Folder & 100%\filename 01.doc"
"Z:\Folder & 100%\filename 02.doc"
"Z:\Folder & 100%\filename 03.doc"
"Z:\Folder & 100%\filename 01.doc"
"Z:\Folder & 90 Percent\filename 01.doc"
```

The top code would fail as the `%` would get skipped.

The code below fixes that issue by doubling any of the characters therefor escaping them.

```batch-file
@echo off & title Example to go through a list of file and echo, Directory then files... & color 5F & chcp 65001 >NUL
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Other code here

rem set "fname=%%~D"
rem This line takes above takes care of any lines in the text file that have
rem percent symbols in by doubling them up to escape them.
:LOOP_THROUGH_LINES_OF_TEXTFILE
set "fileList=%Temp%\music-checker-list.txt"
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%D in (!fileList!) do (
  set "dirBase=%%~dpD"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  if /i not "!dirNext!"=="!dirBase!" echo Directory - "!dirBase:~,-1!"
  endlocal
  set "fname=%%~D" && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && set "nname=!fname:%%=%%%%!"
  call :PROCESS_FILES "!nname!"
  set "dirNext=%%~dpD"
  )
goto :EOF

:PROCESS_FILES
echo Full File Name - "%~f1"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: You have removed the code which ensures that the variables used are not pre-defined. additionally, you've set delayed expansion at the outset, which I didn't do in order to protect any potential exclamation marks in the filename content. I have updated my initial answer to include the ill advised, _(based upon the info provided)_, non `sort` method.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's just that I tried that on a modified list and it used the old variables which mine reads the contents of the file each run.